# PDO::FETCH_OBJ keys prefixed with $

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, pdo, phpunit

I'm wondering if anyone could help me with an issue I'm having with `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` on one table. Every time I do a look up all my parameters are prefixed with a "$" sign for some reason when I'm running tests in PHPUnit.

Outside of my unit tests in my app the parameters are returning the correct name without the prefixed "$".

```
$results = $this->DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM `USER_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS`");
$results->execute();
var_dump($results->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
```

returns inside of my unit tests:

```
array(167) {
    [0] =>
        class stdClass#17 (4) {
        public $id =>
        string(1) "1"
        public $user_key =>
        string(32) "db48cf88b5e20b0a4c2e66a64f70abbd"
        public $login_attempts =>
        string(1) "0"
        public $unlocktime =>
        string(1) "0"
    }
    [1] =>
        class stdClass#256 (4) {
        public $id =>
        string(1) "2"
        public $user_key =>
        string(32) "0494f3807b145170a15a9ea42a717ce3"
        public $login_attempts =>
        string(1) "0"
        public $unlocktime =>
        string(1) "0"
    }
     ...
```

With this table

```
CREATE TABLE `USER_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_key` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `login_attempts` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `unlocktime` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `user_key` (`user_key`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I have other tables in the same database that are return the properties from fetchAll without the prefixed "$" in my unit tests, I'm can't figure where that's coming from in this particular table.

Comment: Are you sure there is a problem? You request objects and var_dump prints out object notation. Maybe you look for the associative-array variante of FETCH_ASSOC?

Comment: All my other model tests in the same database with the same query "select * from table" return the properties without the $ prefix. It's just this one table that's returning these prefixed properties. Switching to FETCH_ASSOC would break my app as it would return an array of arrays not an array of objects.

Comment: Sure, but it looks ok to have the members names prefixed with $ in the php objects, as this is just the php syntax for object properties. I.e. you can access the members e.g. by $my_result_array[0]->id.